# Javascript character (ASCII) to Hex

Tags: javascript, string, character-encoding, hex, ascii

Hey all i am in need of something simple to convert character(s) into ASCII and then make that into a Hex code.

So as an example the "A" character would be:

```
0xF100 + ascii_code = Hex
```

and that would turn out to be:

```
0xF100 + 65 = 0xF141
```

65 would be the character "A" above. I've been looking for some javascript that would take my character and make a Hex from it... But i haven't really found anything that would do this....

Any help would be great!

Comment: Why would you be doing this? 0xF141 is a Private Use code point and should not be used in public information interchange but only by private agreements. There is probably a more reasonable approach to the original problem, whatever it is.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Number's [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) accepts a radix parameter, with which you can convert the ASCII code to hexadecimal like this:

```
var data = "A";
console.log("0xF1" + data.charCodeAt(0).toString(16));
```

16 means base 16, which is hexadecimal.

Comment: What does the (16) do?

Comment: @StealthRT `16` means base 16, which is hexadecimal.

Comment: you can also do .toString(36) which is base 36 which includes letters past 9. I think .toString(2) is to binary.

Comment: `.toString(10)` is decimal

Comment: Just to alert you, if your string contains any character codes below 16, an extra step is needed to zero pad. An example if how to do this is `var c = a.charCodeAt(i);var d = "00"+c.toString(16);var e = d.substr(d.length-2);`