# convert Ascii into Hex in Java Script for comparison

Tags: javascript

I have an Ascii value (something like "@") that I want to convert into an hex in JavaSkript that I can compare this value with some other hex-values.
Are there any casting possiblities?

Best regards and thanks,

Florian

Comment: You can look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580045/javascript-character-ascii-to-hex

Comment: This might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94037/convert-character-to-ascii-code-in-javascript

Comment: What is this _JavaSkript_ you speak of? Do you perhaps mean **Javascript** ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert Ascii strings into base64 (hex)

```
var b64 = btoa("@#%#@!@#$%");
```

Convert base64 to Ascii:

```
atob(b64);
```

Don't know what you want to compare, beside equality.

Comment: +1 for correct and simple answer. [-->More info here<--](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Convert a (UTF-8 or ASCII) string to HEX:
function stringToHex(string) {
  return '0x'+[...string].map(char => char.codePointAt(0).toString(16)).join('')
}
// Convert a HEX string into a number:
function hexToNumber(hex) {
  return parseInt(hex, 16)
}
```