# how get random bytes, and convert it to hex in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to make random bytes and turn it into hexadecimal.

I had used it earlier in php as the id of a database table.

if in php, the code like this

```
function rand_id(){
    return bin2hex(random_bytes(3));
}
```

how to do that in jquery

Comment: Well, a byte would be something like `a` or `g` or `3` or `{`, so just place those in an array and use Math.random to get a random byte.

Comment: [Generate random string/characters in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: it's true, but this "��T0)�" what i get in php,, i thonk i'll try your recomend

Comment: See also [Javascript character (ASCII) to Hex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580045/javascript-character-ascii-to-hex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work on client-side, however will not be cryptographically secure by any means.

```js
function random_hexadecimal(length) {
    var result = '';
    var characters = 'abcdef0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    return result;
}
```

Or for a one-liner (or just shorter and more clean solution):

```js
const size = 20;
let id = [...Array(size)].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16)).join('');

// "6b6a3edaf6f1cbaaf107"
```

For server-side, you can use the following, it is cryptographically secure.

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");
let id = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');

// "bb5dc8842ca31d4603d6aa11448d1654"
```

Comment: Highly inefficient solution. Randomizing per character, which stands for 4 bits, is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Flagging your solution as highly inefficient is a positive contribution to whoever reads your advice. But it's not truly your solution, having copied it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1349426/5524100 (before doing a minor adjustment).